# Providing SDL2 include headers for both Win and Linux in a project

Tags: linux, windows, cross-platform, sdl, sdl-2

I would like to provide all external libaries compiled as a part of my project so that the user doesn't have to download anything. I am using CMake to manage the project. I have an issue with SDL2. Its include files are identical for different platforms except for "SDL_config.h" which is generated when building SDL2 itself and is compiler/platform dependent.

I therefore need to provide two SDL_config.h files - one for windows, and one for linux. If I also want to automate the build process I've come up with two ideas:

1. Put an ifdef _WIN32/unix clause in the SDL header files to include the appropriate SDL_config.h file
2. Keep the SDL files intact and make a build script that would put the correct SDL_config.h file in the include directory

What is the most elegant/usual way of doing what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Put an ifdef _WIN32/unix clause in the SDL header files to include the appropriate SDL_config.h file

Modify library files for such a problem should never be an option, or at least it should be your last resource.

> Keep the SDL files intact and make a build script that would put the correct SDL_config.h file in the include directory

You are using cmake. You don't need a build script.

---

Create a directory and put there the two versions of `SDL_config.h`. Then:

- If you have variables inside you want to replace during the copy (paths or whatever), probably cmake command [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) is what you are looking for:

  > Copy a file to another location and modify its contents
- Otherwise, if all what you want is to copy a file over from a position to a different one, cmake command [`file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) is the way to go in its `COPY` signature:

  > The `COPY` signature copies files, directories, and symlinks to a destination folder.

In both cases, you must use a `WIN32`, `MSVC`, `UNIX`, *whatelse* if/else statement in your `CMakeLists.txt`. Pretty annoying to write and to maintain indeed.

---

That being said, again, you are using cmake. Use it to the end.
Instead of providing the compiled versions for each and every dependency for each and every combination of system and compiler, you can explore cmake module [`ExternalProject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html). By using it you can download and compile on-the-fly dependencies when cmake runs.
This is by far a more elegant solution that doesn't require your users to install manually dependencies in their machines. Moreover, maintenance is easier and you don't have any ugly if/else based on the target system in your `CMakeLists.txt`.